# Округление Decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть число и 40 знаков после запятой. Последнюю цифру дробной части нужно округлить;один раз вверх и один раз вниз.
Запускаю

```
Num = Decimal(123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890)
Delta = Decimal(1/10000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
NumUp = Num + Delta
NumDown = Num - Delta
print('Delta     =   ' '%.40f' % Delta)
print('NumUp     = '   '%.40f' % NumUp)
print('Num       = '   '%.40f' % Num)
print('NumDown   = '   '%.40f' % NumDown)
```

Ожидую получить:

```
Delta     =   0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001
NumUp     = 123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567891
Num       = 123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
NumDown   = 123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567889
```

А получаю:

```
Delta     =   0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001
NumUp     = 123.1234567890123514644074020907282829284668
Num       = 123.1234567890123514644074020907282829284668
NumDown   = 123.1234567890123514644074020907282829284668
```

Как добиться необходимого округления?

Answer (score 3):

У вас точность теряется три раза:

- при создании `Decimal` из `float`
- при операциях с `Decimal`
- при преобразовании `Decimal` в `float` для печати

Можно всё исправить таким образом:

```
from decimal import *
# по умолчанию точность работы с Decimal всего 28 знаков, нам нужно задать "с запасом"
getcontext().prec = 43
# создаём Decimal из литерала, а не из float, чтобы не потерять точность!
Num = Decimal('123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890')
# можно создавать Decimal и таким образом, главное, что не из float
Delta = 1 / Decimal(10000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
NumUp = Num + Delta
NumDown = Num - Delta
# вывод на печать делаем без float-формата, средствами форматирования самого Decimal
print('Delta     =', Delta)
print('NumUp     =', NumUp)
print('Num       =', Num)
print('NumDown   =', NumDown)

Delta     = 1E-40
NumUp     = 123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567891
Num       = 123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
NumDown   = 123.1234567890123456789012345678901234567889
```